# How to pass parameter to dataSet in IReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

When I try to create a table in my report, it asks me to create a dataset.

In the dataset, I type my query that have parameter ID:

```
select * 
from DepositTable 
where id = P{ID}
```

When I try to continue, I get this error message

> General problem: Parameter "ID" does not exist.
>   Check username and password; is the DBMS active ?!

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem 
by adding the paramters itself to the dataset

by right click on dataset and add paramaters